# Can recvmsg() and sendto() be used together?

Tags: sockets

If I have a server and a client, where the client uses `sendto()` to send a message to the server, will it work that the server uses `recvmsg()` to receive this message?

If it doesn't work, is there any method that I can rewrite the code which uses `recvmsg()` to use `recvfrom()`?

Thank you.

Comment: Give me your email address and I'll try to help you with your homework (the array). Put spaces between tokens (anti-spam) if it makes you feel safer.

Comment: @Megrez Could you please accept the answer or post your own answer on how you made both to work together?

Comment: Yes you can. Please refer the answer at [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61790169/2243490)

Answer (score 0):

They are independent.  The protocol (e.g. TCP/UDP) defines the communication semantic and structure.